# Closest hermitian matrix in operator norm induced metric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $M (n)$ be the set of $n \times n$ complex matrices and $\| \cdot \|$ an
operator norm on $M (n)$ arising from some inner-product on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Note the Cartesian Decomposition of $A \in M (n)$ is
$$ A = \left( \frac{A + A^{\ast}}{2} \right) + i \left( \frac{A -
   A^{\ast}}{2 i} \right) . $$
I'd like to show $\frac{A + A^{\ast}}{2}$ is the closest hermitian to $A$ in
the $\| \cdot \|$ induced metric. That is, how to prove
$$ \left\| A - \frac{A + A^{\ast}}{2} \right\| \leqslant \| A - H \| $$
for all hermitian matrices $H$ in $M(n)$?

For the Frobenius norm, I proved the result using $\| H+iK \|_F^2 = \| H\|_F^2+\|K\|_F^2$ (for hermitian $H$ and $K$). Unfortunately, this strategy doesn't work here, and I'm unsure what else to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Note that:
$$\left\|A - \frac{A + A^*}{2}\right\| = \left\|\frac{A - A^*}{2}\right\| = \left\|\frac{(A - H) - (A - H)^*}{2}\right\|,$$
for all Hermitian $H$. Given $A - H$ ranges over all $M(n)$ for $A \in M(n)$ and Hermitian $H$, the conjecture is equivalent to
$$\left\|\frac{A - A^*}{2}\right\| \le \|A\|$$
for all $A \in M(n)$.

Recall that $\|A\|$ is the greatest singular value of $A$, and since $A^*A$ and $AA^*$ share the same (non-zero) eigenvalues, we therefore have $\|A^*\| = \|A\|$. Therefore,
$$\left\|\frac{A - A^*}{2}\right\| \le \frac{\|A\| + \|A^*\|}{2} = \|A\|,$$
as required.